Split a string in JavaScript when last number arise
I want to split the string "111A1A.11111.SL.111FUND II GP_KY.zip" when last number is arise.
string="111A1A.11111.SL.111FUND II GP_KY.zip";
output="FUND II GP_KY.zip";
I tried this but no luck
var string_a = "jkjkhj89898";
var x = string_a.match(/[^\d]+|\d+/g);
console.log(x)


If you want to match 1 or more characters after the last digit, you can use a capture group
.*\d([^\d\n]+)$

The pattern matches:

.* Match the whole line
\d Match a single digit
([^\d\n]+) Capture 1+ chars other than a newline or a digit in group 1
$ End of string

If you want to match 0 or more characters in the capture group:
.*\d(.*)

Example
const regex = /.*\d([^\d\n]+)$/;
const str = "111A1A.11111.SL.111FUND II GP_KY.zip";
const match = str.match(regex);
if (match) {
    console.log(match[1]);
}

Output
FUND II GP_KY.zip



const regex = /.*\d([^\d\n]+)$/;
const str = "111A1A.11111.SL.111FUND II GP_KY.zip";
const match = str.match(regex);
if (match) {
  console.log(match[1]);
}




var string = "111A1A.11111.SL.111FUND II GP_KY.zip";
var lastNumberMatch = string.match(/.*(\d+)(\D+.*)/);
if (lastNumberMatch) {
var output = lastNumberMatch[2];
console.log(output); // "FUND II GP_KY.zip"
}

